# Convert character string into this specific date format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, nvarchar

I am using `SQL Server 2014` and I have a table (t1) which contain a column (ReviewDate) in the `nvarchar` format.

An example of a row of this column is given below:

```
       ReviewDate
  Mr John wrote a review in Oct 2017
```

I need to extract the "date" component from this character string.

To do this, my T-SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT (RIGHT([ReviewDate], 8)) as [ReviewDate 2]
FROM t1
```

This gives me "Oct 2017".

Now, I want to convert the "Oct 2017" into "`2017-10-01`" as a `datetime` format. This is where I am stuck.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, (RIGHT([ReviewDate], 8)), 121) as [ReviewDate2]
```

Above syntax gives me the following error message: "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

```
SELECT CAST( (RIGHT([ReviewDate], 8)) as datetime) as [ReviewDate2]
```

Above syntax gives me the same error message:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Some help will be appreciated.

Comment: Here's a hint.  Try select ReviewDate from TableName where IsDate(RIGHT([ReviewDate], 8)) =0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so far your sample text is a valid datetime in mssql when I tried to cast. It seems there's some invalid data on your table. try using `try_cast()` to include those invalid data.

```
declare @ReviewDate varchar(max)='Mr John wrote a review in Oct 2017'

set  @ReviewDate = (RIGHT(@ReviewDate, 8))

select try_cast(@ReviewDate as datetime) as [ReviewDate2]
```

[dbfiddle<>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=efa10e8fbb1cd8099b596e35cec52111)

Comment: try_cast did the trick. I had some invalid characters in that column!

Comment: @user3115933, great

Answer (score 2):

All your queries are right but make sure that, it should not have any other string apart from date part.

[For example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=34fb6f74f325d778e926f9eb4359f67e) `SELECT CAST('x Oct 2017' AS DATE)` will give you error like

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

```
SELECT CAST((RIGHT('Mr John wrote a review in Oct 2017', 8)) as datetime) as [ReviewDate2]
SELECT CAST('Oct 2017' AS DATE)
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 'Oct  2017 ', 121) as [ReviewDate2]
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cb38a6b4289488acbc98be2af678f3c6)**